# High precision scheduler daemon

Tags: debian, cron, daemon, scheduling

I'm looking for a scheduler daemon like cron, but with at least seconds precision so I can use it for a radio automation app.

I've heard conflicting rumors about cron's ability to handle seconds.  If it is already capable of doing that then I'd be happy to hear that information as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do :

```
* * * * * sleep 5; script.sh
* * * * * sleep 10; script.sh
...
* * * * * sleep 55; script.sh
```

to run the script every 5 seconds.